# Why use the ERC165 standard?

Tags: solidity

When implementing ERC721, why it is necessary to use ERC165 standard?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

interface ERC165 {
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) 
       external view returns (bool);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ERC165` is an interface to check if a contract supports an interface, it's a meta-interface so to say. This is useful if we want to interact with a contract but we don't know if it supports an interface such as `ERC20` or `ERC721`.

As you can guess `supportsInterface` for `ERC165` returns true. Each interface has an `interfaceID`. For ERC165 it is `0x01ffc9a7`. Check the [EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-165.md) for detailed info.