# Is there a way to identify if an address is erc721 or erc1155?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

I would like to know if there is any method of identifying if  an address is erc721 or 1155 without calling the differentiating functions on both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a contract has a method?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30556/how-to-check-if-a-contract-has-a-method)

Comment: Also see this: [Why use the ERC165 standard?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83561/why-use-the-erc165-standard/83571#83571)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IEP-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) you can, I had a similar issue/question this article helped me.

[Solidity get interface id and ERC165 by Nhan Cao](https://nhancv.medium.com/solidity-get-interface-id-and-erc165-190f0e2e3a9)

Hope this helps you out as well!

Answer (score 1):

A detailed solution to your answer is given Stack Overflow. Please do have a look:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706835/how-to-check-if-the-token-on-opensea-is-erc721-or-erc1155-using-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be divided into two cases:

1. *address* supports ERC165 (implements `supportsInterface`), but it is not ERC721;
2. *address* does not support ERC165 (no `supportsInterface` implementation). As an example, it can be ERC20, any Smart Contract, EOA, etc.

**First case**: `nftAddress.supportsInterface(type(IERC721).interfaceId);` returns `false`. Thus your `require` or `if - else` handles it normally.

**Second case**: as `supportsInterface` is not implemented at all, transaction fails without reason.